# Overlay navigation bar & status bar on fullscreen activity

Tags: android, navigationbar, lockscreen

I am creating a lock screen application right now. I have been searching and trying some tricks to do it but still can't find the best approach. My previous approach that I used is to use `TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR`. it worked well. it prevents navigation and `status bar` to get any touches. it also run any other app behind my app, including the power off options dialog.

unfortunately I think this is bad because when the app got freeze or not responding, user can't do anything but force restart his/her phone.

I have been looking and analyze some existing lock screen apps in play store. They use different ways to lock the phone but I found one app that I think I can follow. It makes the nav and status bar overlay the app. nav and status bar still can be clicked but it's all opened behind the lock screen. and when I tried to open the power off dialogs, the `NavigationBar` still overlay the lock screen.

***I changed my app to follow that approach. I am able to make the bars overlay my lock screen but I am still not able to:***

<strike>1. make other app run behind my lock screen (lock screen always on top)</strike>
2. the `NavigationBar` stays overlay when power off dialog appear and when user move to home as well. in my case, the `NavigationBar` pushed up the screen and my screen looks ugly (some components move to wrong place) and <strike>after the `Dialog` dismissed, it doesn't move back to original position.</strike> it's fixed but I noticed a similar problem when I touch the home button and still searching to fix this.

**Here's a snippet of my codes (updated):**

```
   params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE, 
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
                    PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
            params.gravity = Gravity.TOP;

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
            } else {
                getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
            }
    mOverlay = (RelativeLayout) inflater
                    .inflate(R.layout.main, (ViewGroup) null);

    mOverlay.setFitsSystemWindows(false);
            getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(
                    View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY);
            mWindowManager = (WindowManager) context
                    .getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
            mWindowManager.addView(mOverlay, params);
```

**And here a screenshot of app in `PlayStore` that I want to follow:**

[image]

Comment: Do you want to make your own lockscreen? Check out the android lockscreen source to get started.

Comment: @amit I checked your link, unfortunately it's for iOS :(

Comment: @tim yes I do. I already created the lock screen but it's still have some flaws and that's what I am questioning here.

Comment: Hi, how did you manage to get overlay over navigation bar to intercept touches to it? What flags did you set? I am struggling with it for days now, can you help me please?

Comment: I used TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR flag, it makes your app always on top of everything